# playing/pausing MP3 with JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

I have a problem with pausing a currently playing mp3.

For an example, if I run my function like this: `playSong(drake);` it starts running the code out of the first part of my if statement and it's playing the MP3 out of the "drake" object and sets songValue=2
The problem is that it doesn't pause the song if I run it the second time but my console.log gets displayed in the console, so it definitely runs the second part of my if statement when I click it the second time but it doesn't pause the song for some reasons.

```
//object with mp3 audio
var drake = {
    value: 3,
    name: 'Energy',
    artist: 'Drake',
    audio: 'energy.mp3', //
    img: '<img style="width: 50%; margin-right: 25%; margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%;" src="http://www.getrichrapping.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Drake-Energy.jpg">'
};


songValue = 1;

// plays and SHOULD pause a Song
function playSong(object) {
    var Song = new Audio(object.audio);

    //plays the song 
    if (songValue == 1) {

        Song.play();
        songValue = 2;

        // SHOULD pause the song when the functions is runned the second time
    } else if (songValue == 2) {
        console.log("Is it working ?"); // String to test if the "else if" gets runned
        Song.pause();
        songValue = 1;

    }
};
```

Comment: Where is songValue being defined? object.value?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add it but I just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 2 separate functions. One for creating the audio element, and one for playing/pausing a given audio element.

One of your problems is that every time you're calling `playSong()`, you're creating a whole new audio element.

**Solution**

```
var drake = {
    value: 3,
    name: 'Energy',
    artist: 'Drake',
    audio: 'energy.mp3', //
    img: '<img style="width: 50%; margin-right: 25%; margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%;" src="http://www.getrichrapping.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Drake-Energy.jpg">'
};

var audioElement = playSong(drake); // load song and play it

togglePlayPause(audioElement); // pause song

function playSong(object) {
    var Song = new Audio(object.audio);
    Song.play();

    return Song;
}

function togglePlayPause(audioElement) {
    if (audioElement.paused) {
        audioElement.play();
    } else {
        audioElement.pause();
    }
}
```

You first create the audio element and store it in a variable, using the `playSong()` function. Then you pass the audio element in to `togglePlayPause()` to toggle its playing status.

In the example, I'm playing the song and then immediately calling `togglePlayPause()` to pause it again.

Also, you don't need to keep the playing status in a separate variable. I've just used the `.paused` property on the audio element, which returns true if the player has been paused. If you really needed a separate variable, you should store it within the drake object as a new property `.isPlaying`.

https://jsfiddle.net/5k38da10/

Answer (score 0):

move the var Song = new Audio(object.audio) outside playSong.

You essentially make a new audio each time you call the function!

of course you would need to make changes to reference the object.audio since object is not a global.

A better way is to do like this:

```js
//object with mp3 audio
var drake = {
  value: 3,
  name: 'Energy',
  artist: 'Drake',
  audio: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3', //
  img: '<img style="width: 50%; margin-right: 25%; margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%;" src="http://www.getrichrapping.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Drake-Energy.jpg">'
};


songValue = 1;

// plays and SHOULD pause a Song
function playSong(object) {

  //plays the song 
  if (songValue == 1) {
    var player = document.getElementById('song');
    var sourceMp3 = document.getElementById('sourceMp3');

    sourceMp3.src = object.audio;

    player.load(); //just start buffering (preload)
    player.play(); //start playing

    songValue = 2;

    // SHOULD pause the song when the functions is runned the second time
  } else if (songValue == 2) {
    console.log("Is it working ?"); // String to test if the "else if" gets runned
    var player = document.getElementById('song');

    if (!player.paused)
      player.pause();
    songValue = 1;

  }
};
```

```html
<audio id="song" controls="controls">
  <source id="sourceMp3" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p>
  <button onclick='playSong(drake)'> Play Song </button>
</p>
```

Referenced fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm6ky/2/

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6jgjewg/2/

Comment: Thanks, but then "object" within the var Song is not defined and I need it like this because I want to play different audio mp3's

Comment: try to get hold of the Audio instance via some javascript code - getElementById perhaps!

Comment: sorry I dont get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You should store you Audio object in your base object like this

```
if (object.song == undefined){
    object.song = new Audio(object.audio);
}
```

And use `object.song` instead of the Song variable

You can user the `object.song.paused(boolean)` to know if the song is paused or not and launch the song again.